# Nuxt i18n: Using `nuxtI18nHead` in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I'm struggling with `nuxtI18nHead` and TypeScript, what should I do to avoid this error?

The below is from `default.vue`

Code:

```
import MainNavbar from '~/components/MainNavbar.vue'

export default {
  components: { MainNavbar },
  head (): any {
    return this.$nuxtI18nHead({ addSeoAttributes: true })
  }
}
```

Error:

```
 ERROR  ERROR in layouts/default.vue:18:17                                                                                                                                                 21:34:24
TS2339: Property '$nuxtI18nHead' does not exist on type '{ components: { MainNavbar: ExtendedVue<Vue, unknown, unknown, unknown, Record<never, any>>; }; head(): any; }'.
    16 |   components: { MainNavbar },
    17 |   head (): any {
  > 18 |     return this.$nuxtI18nHead({ addSeoAttributes: true })
       |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    19 |   }
    20 | }
    21 |
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `export default Vue.extend({})` instead to declare your component? Not sure Typescript is able to strongly type your component like this.

Comment: @Kapcash I don't think you're allowed to use `Vue.extend({})` on the `default.vue` component, I could be wrong though, I'll try it tonight and let you know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by using `Vue.extend({})`, for some reason I thought you weren't allowed to use that in the `default.vue` file.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import MainNavbar from '~/components/MainNavbar.vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  components: { MainNavbar },
  head (): any {
    return this.$nuxtI18nHead({ addSeoAttributes: true })
  }
})
```

Thanks @Kapcash for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle that is create a global Vue type shim so that it's not necessary to explicitly `Vue.extend` in all Vue components.

Create a file like `types/vue-shim.d.ts` with content:

```
declare module '*.vue' {
    import Vue from 'vue';
    export default Vue;
}
```

See also https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/guide/setup that documents this and other typescript-related setup steps.